# Correct way to reference to a percentage value's category/label

Tags: conventions, units, metrology

When a percentage is written as, for example: 20% of sold products were of product A and 80% product B.  What is the correct concept / word to use to describe "product A"?  Is it units?

As percentages are unitless I think it is not correct to say "product A" are the units.  But then you can also say that this calculation is valid: `20% (of sold products were of product A) * 100 units * £10 profit per product A = £200 profit from product A`.  Where as it would be meaningless to use the value of "80% (of sold products were of product B)" in that calculation.

Apologies if I have not worded this question very clearly or if the answer is easy to find once you know what to search for.

Comment: The correct way for 100 units sold. P (A)=Profit from $P(A)=0.2*100A*10A/£=200£$

Comment: I’m voting to close this post (v2) because it seems not about physics.

Comment: Thanks @trula but it's not 100 units of A it's 100 units of A+B of which 20% are of A?

Comment: @Qmechanic can you suggest which stackexchange might be open to this question please?  I could change it to use meters etc if that would help?

Comment: I said 100 units sold, so there are 0.2 units A sold. but P(A) is the profit from A

Comment: See section 5.4.2 of the SI brochure. https://www.nist.gov/pml/special-publication-330 “Units are never qualified by further information about the nature of the quantity; any extra information on the nature of the quantity should be attached to the quantity symbol and not to the unit symbol.”

Comment: Oh that's great!  Thank you very much @Dale!  I've just posted this as a question on https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610559/correct-way-to-reference-to-a-percentage-values-category-label if you want to add your answer there you'd be welcome to :-)

Comment: Actually I deleted the question on english.stackexchange because you referenced the "Physical Measurement Laboratory" so that sounds related enough to Physics. That and others will find your comment under this question.  Thanks again @Dale there's no chance I would have known to search for "quantity symbols"

Comment: No worries. I think it was on topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See section 5.4.2 of the [SI brochure](https://nist.gov/pml/special-publication-330). This brochure describes both the SI units themselves and also the use of units in scientific writing.

“Units are never qualified by further information about the nature of the quantity; any extra information on the nature of the quantity should be attached to the quantity symbol and not to the unit symbol.”

So in your case the quantities are dimensionless and will have no units. The percent symbol, $\%$, is not a unit, it is simply a symbol meaning $\%=0.01$.

All information about the nature of the quantity is in the quantity symbol. So in your text you would define something like “$x_{A}$ is the number of sold products of type A over the total number of sold products” and then later you would say something like “$x_A=32.1 \ \%$”.

Comment: Ah, % as a symbol meaning 0.01 is also eye opening, that makes so much sense.  Thank you Dale!